# Why won't the Spotify response allow me to go past when an error is received?

Tags: ruby, api, http, error-handling, spotify

I'm simply trying to look up a user and if the user exists, sweet, if not, I want to state so...

```
# Install if you haven't already
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'rspotify'

# Twilio Security Access
account_sid = 'enter_your_sid'
auth_token = 'enter_your_auth_token'

# Spotify User Lookup
def user_lookup(user_search)
    spotify_user = RSpotify::User.find(user_search)
end

# Crafted text message using Twilio
def text(account_sid, auth_token, message)
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

    client.messages.create(
        from: '+twilio_number', # I guess you can use my number for testing
        to: '+personal_number', # Feel free to enter your number to get the messages
        body: message
    )
end

# Ask who you should lookup on Spotify
puts "Who would you like to look up? "
user_input_1 = gets.chomp

# Make sure the user exists
if user_lookup(user_input_1).id != user_input_1 # Test with "zxz122"
    msg = "Could not find that Spotify user!"
    text(account_sid, auth_token, msg)
    puts "Spotify user details send failure!"
else
    user_exist = user_lookup(user_input_1)
    user_profile_url = "https://open.spotify.com/user/#{user_input_1}"
    msg = "Check out #{user_input_1} on Spotify: #{user_profile_url}"
    text(account_sid, auth_token, msg)
    puts "Spotify user details have been sent!"
end
```

The response I keep getting is...

```
`return!': 404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)
```

So why is it not hitting my if statement and triggering "Could not find that Spotify user!"??

Comment: Take a look how to handle `RestClient's errors` in their [readme](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#response-callbacks-error-handling)

Comment: Yea - I spent a few hours doing that and while I seemed to get close on some, none ended up working out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? The creator of `RestClient` designed the gem to raise an exception if a resource doesn't exist (aka returns a `404 not found`).

To work around this behavior just change the method to:

```
def user_lookup(user_search)
  RSpotify::User.find(user_search) rescue false
end
```

And change your `if ... else` block to:

```
if user_lookup(user_input_1)
  user_profile_url = "https://open.spotify.com/user/#{user_input_1}"
  msg = "Check out #{user_input_1} on Spotify: #{user_profile_url}"
  text(account_sid, auth_token, msg)
  puts "Spotify user details have been sent!"
else
  msg = "Could not find that Spotify user!"
  text(account_sid, auth_token, msg)
  puts "Spotify user details send failure!"
end
```

Comment: Okay - I tried adding the "rescue false" and now this happens: `spotify_user_lookup.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method `id' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Nevermind! I changed my if condition to `user_lookup(user_input_1) == false` which seems to be doing the trick. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Thanks! It wont let me upvote since I don't have enough reputation yet I guess. I gave it the check mark though!